# Images not updating in laravel 4

Tags: jquery, laravel-4

I have a page where I can update my gallery and everything updates except for my images. If I use

```
echo "<PRE>";
print_r($input);
die();
```

Then I see that everything except for the image has been posted. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with this.

My GalleryController.php

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $galleries = Gallery::find($id);

    if(is_null($galleries)){
        return Redirect::route('admin.gallery.edit');
    }

    return View::make('gallery::edit', compact('galleries'));
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 * PUT /gallery/{id}
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function update($id)
{
    $input = Input::all();
    $validation = Validator::make($input, Gallery::$rules);

    if($validation->fails()){
        return Redirect::route('admin.gallery.edit')
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors($validation)
            ->with('message', 'There were validation errors');
    }

    if($validation->passes()){
        $galleries = Gallery::FindOrFail($id);
        // echo "<PRE>";
        // print_r($galleries);
        // die();
        $galleries->update($input);

        echo "<PRE>";
        print_r($input);
        die();

        return Redirect::route('admin.gallery.index', $id);
    }
}
```

My edit.blade.php

```
@extends('templates::admin')
@section('content')

<script>
$(".add-form").submit(function(event){
    $(this).find(".test-upload").each(function(){
        var image = [];
        $(this).parent().find(".ajax-file-upload-statusbar").each(function()   {
            image.push($.trim($(this).find(".ajax-file-upload-filename").html()));
        });
        $(this).parent().find(".img-hidden").val(JSON.stringify(image));
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        encode : true,
    });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var settings = {
            url: '{{ asset("upload/upload.php") }}',
            //checkExisting : '{{ asset("vendor/afishinsea/uploadify/check-exists.php?target=banners_images") }}',
            dragDrop:true,
            multiple : false,
            showFileCounter:false,
            showDone: false,
            fileName: "myfile",
            allowedTypes:"jpg,png,gif,pdf", 
            returnType:"json",
            showDelete:true,
        }
</script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        {{ Form::model($galleries, array('method' => 'PATCH', 'route' => array('admin.gallery.update', $galleries->id))) }}
    <div class="form">
        <div>
            {{ Form::label('title', 'Title') }}
        </div>
        <div>
            {{ Form::text('title', $galleries->title, array('id' => 'title', 'class' => 'form-control')) }}
        </div>
        <div>
            {{ Form::label('content', 'Content') }}
        </div>
        <div>
            {{ Form::textarea('content', $galleries->content) }}
        </div>




<div class="image_uploader">
<div id="fileuploader-{{ $galleries->id }}" class="test-upload">Upload</div>
{{ getImages($galleries->image) }}
<script>
    var uploadObj = $(".test-upload").uploadFile(settings);
</script>
{{ Form::hidden('image', '', array('id' => 'img-add_'.$galleries->id, 'class' => 'img-hidden')) }}
</div>




        <div>
            {{ Form::submit('Submit', array('class' => 'btn btn-default', 'role' => 'button')) }}
        </div>
    </div>
{{ Form::open() }}

@if($errors->any())
    <ul>
        {{ implode('', $errors->all('<li class="error">:message</li>')) }}
    </ul>
@endif
    </div>
</div>
@stop
```

My upload.php

```
<?php
$output_dir = "../uploads/";
if(isset($_FILES["myfile"]))
{
$ret = array();

//  This is for custom errors;  
/*  $custom_error= array();
$custom_error['jquery-upload-file-error']="File already exists";
echo json_encode($custom_error);
die();
*/
$error =$_FILES["myfile"]["error"];
//You need to handle  both cases
//If Any browser does not support serializing of multiple files using  FormData() 
if(!is_array($_FILES["myfile"]["name"])) //single file
{
    $fileName = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir.$fileName);
    $ret[]= $fileName;
}
else  //Multiple files, file[]
{
  $fileCount = count($_FILES["myfile"]["name"]);
  for($i=0; $i < $fileCount; $i++)
  {
    $fileName = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"][$i];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"] [$i],$output_dir.$fileName);
    $ret[]= $fileName;
  }

}
echo json_encode($ret);
}
?>
```

UPDATE
I edited my code in my view to have

```
{{ Form::model($galleries, array('files' => 'true', 'method' => 'PATCH', 'route' => array('admin.gallery.update', $galleries->id))) }}
```

and I added this code in my controller

```
dd($input);
```

and this is what I got when I tried to edit my item

> array (size=5)
>    '_method' => string 'PATCH' (length=5)
>    '_token' => string 'cOOg56pbcKJ3BDgsQWL6MGxK4CO1SXdGRq8rd1rV' (length=40)
>    'title' => string 'test' (length=4)
>    'content' => string '
>
> test
>
> ' (length=11)
>    'image' => string '' (length=0)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the `'files' => true` setting in your `Form::model` call. I've never used it on Form::model, but I'd imagine you'd want to write:

```
{{ Form::model($galleries, array('method' => 'PATCH', 'route' => array('admin.gallery.update', $galleries->id), 'files' => true)) }}
```

Comment: Hmm, and if you change it to  `Form::open( array('method' => 'PATCH', 'route' => array('admin.gallery.update', $galleries->id), 'files' => true))` as a test, does that show the image?

Comment: Ahh but your image is being uploaded by AJAX through your jQuery plugin, not on the submit of the form. So you won't see it in the udate method of your controller. you have to look in your `upload/upload.php` file, that's where the `uploadFile` plugin is sending the file.

Comment: I've updated my question to include the upload.php. I still don't understand why my upload.php would be of interest, because it does upload to the specified folder, it just doesn't save to the database.